# extjs combo not defined error

Tags: extjs

I have a Panel. Inisde the Panel, I do a `initComponent: function() {this.someCombo = new someDefaultCombo(...)}`
Then I do:

```
this.somePredefinedForm.items.add(someCombo); //Line 2
```

And I get:

```
Error: someCombo is not defined
```

at Line2.

But I am defining it at the top. So why there is js error?

EDIT: When I changed this to:`this.somePredefinedForm.items.add(this.someCombo);` , the error went away. But why?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the script link reference is actually resolving? You can do this with Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Also, your script reference needs to be AFTER the reference to the ExtJS library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.someCombo` is te way to access someCombo. This is the object in Panel not something global like you try at the begining

Answer (score 1):

if you are executing this:

```
this.somePredefinedForm.items.add(this.someCombo);
```

not in **initComponent** function then make sure that **this** refers to object that contains **initComponent** function.